# Script file with multiple commands

Tags: oracle, plsql

How can I run below script file in SQL*Plus.

Script file content:

```
variable a number; 

begin 
:a := 10; 
end; 

print a;
```

How can I execute this in SQL*Plus?

**EDIT**

Script file name is: Question3.sql

I am getting following error:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to execute a PL/SQL block in SQL*PLUS, you have to terminate it with the slash `/`. So, your file should look like this:

```
-- some_name.sql file
variable a number; 
begin 
  :a := 10; 
end; 
/
print a; 


SQL> @c:\some_name.sql

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


         A                                                                      
----------                                                                      
        10
```

You could also use `exec` SQL*PLUS command to execute a single line command - assign a value to a bind variable in your case. `exec` command implicitly wraps a statement you are trying to execute in the `begin end` block:

```
-- some_name.sql file
variable a number; 
exec :a := 10; 
print a; 

SQL> @c:\some_name.sql

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


         A                                                                      
----------                                                                      
        10
```